# How to make multiple right joins in one single command for different child tables?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

On the followin image you see 3 tables: A, B , C.
A: Is the table that holds the foreign keys from B and C

[image]

[image]

If I do a right join between A and B on that foreign key, it works, meaning I get the data from column fooB. Same between A and C with fooC.

But If I put both right joins under the same command it fails with null

```
+-------------+---------------+
| fooB        | fooC          |
+-------------+---------------+
| NULL        | abc           |
| NULL        | xyz           |
```

*This is slightly different as the image with the commands posted below, as this comes straight from the real deployment, however cmds below still show that both columns do not show up.

I've tried mixin up left joins, right joins , outer joins all with same result.
I have googled about this, but the way my question is formulated is awkard and the hits I get return the traditional right joins for just one table.

How do I get this to work in one command? CMDS Below:

[image]

Same commands as above but in text, as comments are asking for text rather than images:

```
MariaDB [joinPOC]> select fooB from tableA right join tableB on tableB_idtableB=tableB.idtableB;
+------+
| fooB |
+------+
| b1   |
| b2   |
| b3   |
+------+
3 rows in set (0.001 sec)

MariaDB [joinPOC]> select fooC from tableA right join tableC on tableC_idtableC=tableC.idtableC;
+------+
| fooC |
+------+
| c1   |
| c2   |
| c3   |
+------+
3 rows in set (0.001 sec)

MariaDB [joinPOC]> select fooB from tableA right join tableB on tableB_idtableB=tableB.idtableB right join tableC on tableC_idtableC=tableC.idtableC;
+------+
| fooB |
+------+
| b1   |
| b2   |
| b3   |
+------+
```

--HERE IS THE ENTIRE SCRIPT--

```
-- MySQL Workbench Forward Engineering

SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema joinPOC
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS `joinPOC` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema joinPOC
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `joinPOC` ;
USE `joinPOC` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `joinPOC`.`tableB`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `joinPOC`.`tableB` (
  `idtableB` INT NOT NULL,
  `fooB` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idtableB`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `joinPOC`.`tableC`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `joinPOC`.`tableC` (
  `idtableC` INT NOT NULL,
  `fooC` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idtableC`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `joinPOC`.`tableA`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `joinPOC`.`tableA` (
  `idtableA` INT NOT NULL,
  `fooA` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  `tableB_idtableB` INT NOT NULL,
  `tableC_idtableC` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idtableA`),
  INDEX `fk_tableA_tableB_idx` (`tableB_idtableB` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_tableA_tableC1_idx` (`tableC_idtableC` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_tableA_tableB`
    FOREIGN KEY (`tableB_idtableB`)
    REFERENCES `joinPOC`.`tableB` (`idtableB`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_tableA_tableC1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`tableC_idtableC`)
    REFERENCES `joinPOC`.`tableC` (`idtableC`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Data for table `joinPOC`.`tableB`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
START TRANSACTION;
USE `joinPOC`;
INSERT INTO `joinPOC`.`tableB` (`idtableB`, `fooB`) VALUES (1, 'b1');
INSERT INTO `joinPOC`.`tableB` (`idtableB`, `fooB`) VALUES (2, 'b2');
INSERT INTO `joinPOC`.`tableB` (`idtableB`, `fooB`) VALUES (3, 'b3');

COMMIT;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Data for table `joinPOC`.`tableC`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
START TRANSACTION;
USE `joinPOC`;
INSERT INTO `joinPOC`.`tableC` (`idtableC`, `fooC`) VALUES (1, 'c1');
INSERT INTO `joinPOC`.`tableC` (`idtableC`, `fooC`) VALUES (2, 'c2');
INSERT INTO `joinPOC`.`tableC` (`idtableC`, `fooC`) VALUES (3, 'c3');

COMMIT;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Data for table `joinPOC`.`tableA`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
START TRANSACTION;
USE `joinPOC`;
INSERT INTO `joinPOC`.`tableA` (`idtableA`, `fooA`, `tableB_idtableB`, `tableC_idtableC`) VALUES (1, 'a1', 1, 1);
INSERT INTO `joinPOC`.`tableA` (`idtableA`, `fooA`, `tableB_idtableB`, `tableC_idtableC`) VALUES (2, 'a2', 2, 2);
INSERT INTO `joinPOC`.`tableA` (`idtableA`, `fooA`, `tableB_idtableB`, `tableC_idtableC`) VALUES (3, 'a3', 3, 3);

COMMIT;
```

Desired output in a single command:

```
+-------------+---------------+
| fooB        | fooC          |
+-------------+---------------+
| b1          | c1            |
| b2          | c2            |
```

Comment: Reformulate to change from `RIGHT` to `LEFT` -- that is what most people are used to reading.  Use `ON` for saying how tables are related; `WHERE` for filtering.  If necessary, add parens.  Use aliases for each table.  Show us the query.

Comment: I tried LEFT running the command individually and that did not work.. no need for WHERE in my case, thats the idea of getting the SELECT fooB is for... alright let me get you the "minimal -reproducible" and edit the question

Comment: `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and show us the failing query.

Comment: `show create table` not working for me, i have added commands as img, last command I expect to fill information from both columns, instead it only displays one.

Comment: Text, not screen shots.  What is in the tables to start with?  What is the desired results?

Comment: withour seeing your example data when you have 3 tables, you need conctions between all so that he row that conbnect tabe1 with table2 also finds a partner in table3, so that all columns are filled, what i usually do is showing all columns of all tables and then trying the different joisn and on

Comment: I added screenshots and entire script with inserts, this is a noob question, what else is needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is an INNER JOIN.

To exclude rows, you can use the normal WHERE clause or do it in the ON clause

**Schema (MySQL v8.0)**

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT 
    b.fooB, c.fooC
FROM
    tableA a
        INNER JOIN
    tableB b ON a.tableB_idtableB = b.idtableB
        INNER JOIN
    tableC c ON a.tableC_idtableC = c.idtableC;

| fooB | fooC |
| ---- | ---- |
| b1   | c1   |
| b2   | c2   |
| b3   | c3   |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wUqVKNZy96RjR7hTk3md7o/22)